# fullCalendar in Bootstrap Popover - content only shows once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar, bootstrap-popover

I would like to use a Bootstrap Popover to contain a fullCalendar instance, so that when a user performs a specified event (in the MVE, a click on a button) the calendar is shown until being dismissed (here, by clicking on the button again). There are other requirements (such as pulling event data via an AJAX call) but I've gotten them working and they aren't relevant to the problem at hand, as the problem happens even when a blank calendar is used.

I've successfully gotten the popover/calendar combo appearing, but only the first time the button is clicked. Once the popover is dismissed and the button is clicked a second time, the popover shows up without the calendar. Obviously, the calendar needs to appear every time the button is clicked, but I haven't been able to figure out why that isn't happening. Originally it seemed like the problem was that the popover had already been turned into a fullCalendar, and didn't like more calls, but that doesn't seem right.

[MVE can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/oc4nqsdm/24/), code is below.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="test-button">Calendar Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#test-button').popover({
    container: 'body',
    title: "Booking Schedule", 
    placement:'bottom',
    html: 'yes'
});

$('#test-button').on('click', function() {
    $('.popover-content').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        maxTime: '12:00:00',
        nowIndicator: true,
        timezone: 'Australia/Brisbane',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events
    });
});
```

Libraries

- jQuery 3.2.1
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- momentJS 2.20.1
- fullCalendar 3.9.0

Comment: I wonder if bootstrap is destroying and re-creating the popover HTML each time? Can you tell from your DOM whether it's just hidden, or re-created with new elements? I'm only thinking maybe you'd have to re-initialise the calendar each time too

Comment: @ADyson It does indeed look like it's being destroyed and recreated - when clicked once, the popover div was created with id 'popover262999', when it was dismissed, that element disappeared from the DOM, and when the button was clicked again, the new popover div had the id 'popover371557'. As a quick and dirty test, pointing fullCalendar at the new ID (https://jsfiddle.net/oc4nqsdm/27/) worked. If you want to put up an answer, I'll happily accept it!

Comment: @ADyson Hm, although, when I try to put the fullCalendar in the actual popover-content section via the selector $('#' + id).find('.popover-content') (https://jsfiddle.net/oc4nqsdm/28/) it reverts to the previous behaviour. I don't suppose you'd be able to help me work out why that is, and how to avoid it?